# Pub/Sub - Acknowledgement deadline is ignored when used Exactly once delivery

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

With enabled `Exactly once delivery` and Acknowledgement deadline set to `600s` , the message receiver still gets message earlier - in 60s or less.
This is my current testing code:

```
        final Subscriber subscriber = pubSubTemplate.getPubSubSubscriberTemplate().
                subscribe("projects/xxxx/subscriptions/xxx-topic-sub", m -> {
                    final String s = m.getPubsubMessage().getData().toStringUtf8();

                    logger.info("sub1 = " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " = " + s + " " + m.getPubsubMessage().getMessageId());
                    try {
                        logger.info("Processing in progress - going to sleep 5 minutes...");
                        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 5);
                        logger.info("Sleeping over");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        subscriber.awaitRunning();


        for (; ; ) {
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
```

And this is the output - note the timestamps among messages:

```
08:19:06.277  INFO 26172 --- [sub-subscriber1] GcpTest    : sub1 = global-gcp-pubsub-subscriber1 = HELLO 5185509958571237
08:19:06.278  INFO 26172 --- [sub-subscriber1] GcpTest    : Processing in progress - going to sleep 5 minutes...
08:20:27.810  INFO 26172 --- [sub-subscriber2] GcpTest    : sub1 = global-gcp-pubsub-subscriber2 = HELLO 5185509958571237
08:20:27.810  INFO 26172 --- [sub-subscriber2] GcpTest    : Processing in progress - going to sleep 5 minutes...
08:21:57.854  INFO 26172 --- [sub-subscriber3] GcpTest    : sub1 = global-gcp-pubsub-subscriber3 = HELLO 5185509958571237
08:21:57.855  INFO 26172 --- [sub-subscriber3] GcpTest    : Processing in progress - going to sleep 5 minutes...
```

I am using the latest version of

```
    implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:3.3.0")
```

What's causing this? I also don't understand settings like `maxAckExtensionPeriod`. The documentation does not cover this.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vity, Are you trying to publish the same message to all the subscribers? Looking into your output it seems like the same message is published to all 3 subscribers, to prevent message delivery to other subscribers you can `Enable ack messages` when publishing the message. Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: There is technically only 1 subscriber instance in the code (you see all code I have). The client implementation runs 4 threads on the background (note the thread names).
The problem is the message is redelivered from the GCP PubSub before 600s passed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide me more information about the subscription and project so I can better assist you, if you are comfortable sharing?

The behavior you are seeing is possibly due to some failed ack deadline extension requests. The client libraries currently issue ack deadline extensions periodically. These extensions can be smaller or greater than the default ack deadline provided in the subscription definition.

To get around this behavior, a user can set [minDurationPerAckExtension](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.Builder#com_google_cloud_pubsub_v1_Subscriber_Builder_setMinDurationPerAckExtension_org_threeten_bp_Duration_) so that the ack deadline extension is not less than the value provided. A user can also provide [maxDurationPerAckExtension](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.Builder#com_google_cloud_pubsub_v1_Subscriber_Builder_setMaxDurationPerAckExtension_org_threeten_bp_Duration_), so that the ack deadline extension is not greater than the value provided.

Comment: Thank you @Mahesh for your answer. There is nothing special about my project. Just the code I mentioned above. The subscription has enabled Exactly once delivery with 600s deadline, but the message is redelivered before this dead line. I emulated longer request processing to see how the Exact delivery works, but the behavior is different against message in Sub settings - "When enabled, messages sent to the subscription are guaranteed not to be resent before the message’s ack deadline expires..."
I am not sure if the problem resists inside client libraries or the Pub/Sub itself.

Comment: `com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubConfiguration.Subscriber` does not provide `minDurationPerAckExtension` property, only `maxAckExtensionPeriod` is available. To use it it's necessary to rewrite `SubscriberFactory` (`DefaultSubscriberFactory`) and tons of other configuration in the current Java PubSub library...
I don't understand the Ack extension mechanism, but obviously the client library ignores settings from the server PubSub subscription and uses its own 60s default value.

Comment: Can you tell me what you see in the metrics reported as described here? https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery#understand_the_metric

For minDurationPerAckExtension, we are working on getting that updated.

Comment: sorry for the delay. Here it is:
Metrics: https://i.postimg.cc/yY18gYc3/subscriptionmetrics.png , Related logs: https://i.postimg.cc/qBX7vChd/simple-app-log.png

Comment: On the top left graph, you can see that there are non zero expired ack deadlines. In such cases, redeliveries are expected to ensure no data loss.  

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1201 is tracking the support for minDurationPerAckExtension.

Once available, I advice setting it to be the same as your default ack deadline. This should hopefully help avoid cases where ack deadlines expire due to very short leases.

Comment: I still don't understand the flow of the ACK/redelivery messages. With current subscription settings the behavior is strange and unexpected. There is no reason for redelivery not even for a additional change any of the client configuration parameters. It should be adapted by the subscription settings.

Comment: As I mentioned before, from the graph you provided, we can see that there are non zero ack expiration. Ack expirations lead to redeliveries, because Pub/Sub service isn't sure of the client state. For example, a client processing a message might have crashed. In such a case, redelivery of the message is expected, otherwise the client would never re-process the message (aka data loss).

The follow up question is why are we seeing ack deadline expirations. There could be a few reasons including the client tasks being unhealthy and not able to send a timely modifyAckDeadline request.

Answer (score 0):

Pub/Sub guarantees at-least-once message delivery, which means that occasional duplicates are to be expected.

As mentioned in [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#pull-subscription), the subscriber client controls the rate of delivery and it can dynamically modify the acknowledgement deadline, allowing message processing to be arbitrarily long.

Pub/Sub usually redeliver the message when it is not acknowledged after the acknowledgement deadline, but this is not guaranteed. Here in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery), it means the message may get re-delivered before the acknowledgement deadline.

So, summarizing, subscriber clients can dynamically modify the acknowledgement deadline of messages in order to guarantee at-least-once delivery or to provide enough time for messages to be properly processed by the subscriber; as a result, occasional duplicates may be expected.

If you're publishing messages in large batches, however can't ack every message in the batch before the ACK deadline. So there are chances of messages getting re-delivered.

If the number of messages in a batch isn't high, the issue will need further investigation, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: Thank you @Prajna Rai T for you answer, I think it's a client library issue. 
As you can see there was only 1 message in the Pub/Sub queue and the library obviously ignores the 600s Ack. deadline in Pub/Sub settings when the *Exactly once* is enabled - https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery  - "No redelivery occurs while a message is outstanding. A message is considered outstanding until the acknowledgment deadline expires or the message is acknowledged."
Also it's not easy to modify the `minDurationPerAckExtension` mentioned by Mahesh (that's probably another issue).