# Pub/Sub re-sending message after 10 sec even setting ack deadline 600 sec. How to overcome this issue?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using Pub/Sub for message delivery and I have set the ack. deadline 600 sec which is maximum but still If I'm not able to process that record within 10sec then It re-sends the same message again. Because of this, It's delivering a duplicate message.

So, Is there anything else I need to configure in Pub/Sub subscription? I have also configured the Retry policy as Immediate, should I set it so exponential back off?

Comment: Are you sure that you have only 1 subscription?

Comment: yes only one subscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub supported client libraries update the ack deadlines automatically.

Please consider exploring [Exactly once delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery) to avoid duplicate deliveries.

Related answer: [Pub/Sub - Acknowledgement deadline is ignored when used Exactly once delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73076103/pub-sub-acknowledgement-deadline-is-ignored-when-used-exactly-once-delivery)